# listview in onPost Execute not able to display

Tags: android, database

i didnt get any error in this but i cant able to see the data in my emulator. there also i didnt get any forceclose. activity is running. i get all my print sts successfully. i dont know want im missing what i should add any one help me thanks in advance.
My code is

> My onPostExecute

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
  super.onPostExecute(toString());
  pDialog.dismiss();
  groupnamelist=new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(tnamelist));
  System.out.println("List Success :"+tnamelist);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
            // selecting single ListView item
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>    
      (Topic.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));

    System.out.println("Before call another class Topic names :"+groupnamelist);

            return;
 }
```

i didnt get any error in my LogCat any one help what im missing in this?

Comment: im getting error i log.d  any one can help me i thanks lot to you..helpers...

Comment: what is jsonParser and even groups?

Comment: Post your entire stack trace.

Comment: in if i want to code many things before that itself im not able to execute

Comment: now check plz i wrote full code for doInBackground help me thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data that you are receiving from the URL is XML and not JSON. Check the data source manually first, and that you're not getting a 404 or something.

Comment: now check plz i wrote full code for doInBackground help me thanks a lot

Comment: Dude. "Value !DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" means there is something wrong with the JSON file. Check that first before I look at your code.

Comment: thanks a lot im getting upto      System.out.println("Checking ::"+gname); i got my group name. but i didnt got in emulator. i got in logcat. thks a lot. plz help me to get in emulator...

Comment: Again, post the JSON file you're processing if you want help.

Comment: I meant, post `url_get_allgrades`.

Comment: see my url_get_allgrades help me im getting the value. but not able display the group name. in my database also id is all correct. help me thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Now my getting this warning  Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of:com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4064c180

Comment: can you just post the output of url_get_allgrades? I just want to see the JSON output. Not the PHP code.

Comment: i cant understand im new to android. what output u need see my logcat

Comment: The JSON file that the server sends... looks like this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/com.ibm.etools.iwd.doc/images/defaultjson.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot...i got it. now the problem is i need a expandablelistview when i click on child of first expandablelistview.

Comment: can  u explain how see the json output im new to android. but i got the output.now problem is on expandablelistview

Comment: Open the file with your browser. Make sure the data you get is valid. I don't think it is.

Comment: im getting this error Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 10.0.2.2  says Try Reloading. I don't know bro..

Comment: I got the output bro..now i want too get expand from my child click. How should i do. help me thanks in advance..

Comment: Check the API examples to learn how: http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: i left that idea of expandablelist now im trying that if i click on child i should a list in another activity...i finished that but one small problem in Onpost Execute i want display the list view. i set the adapter but i cant see that data there is no error in my logcat my print sts are sucessfully showing till last..

Comment: Different problem, you need to open a different question. Can't just keep editing the same question and changing it...

Comment: However use this constructor instead to set the data: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html.  ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, T[])

Comment: i set ArrayAdapter but not able to see the data